# Firebase (android)- detect if reference exists inside transaction

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a transaction on Firebase, during the transaction I am updating several locations because of the denormalization.

One of this updates should only be if a reference exists, else, it shouldn't write.

As I understand, using setValueChangedListener is async so the transaction will end before the value can be checked.

How can I do this? Or must I check this value before starting the transaction?

This is the method removing the non important things:

1. First it queries user
2. Then updates user reference to a building
3. Then updates building's users
4. Then I want to update another object's users, but only if object exists, as it can change everyday.

   ```
   @Override public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

      User user = mutableData.getValue(User.class);
      if (user == null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "User " + userId + " was locally null");
          return Transaction.success(mutableData);
      }

      user.couponCode = code.key; //gotten from before

      //add code address to user
      user.addresses = new HashMap<String, Address>();
      user.addresses.put(code.key,code.address);

      Database.child(Constants.FB_HOUSES).child(code.address.key).child(Constants.FB_RESIDENTS).child(user.key).setValue(user.getUserResidentObject());

      //Add new resident to tasks if any
      *** HERE I WANT TO QUERY OTHER PATH TO DO SOMETHING

      mutableData.setValue(user);

      return Transaction.success(mutableData);
   }
   ```

Comment: A transaction handler gets the current value of the node it runs on as its input. You just have to be prepared that the transaction handler will initially be run with null. If that doesn't allow you to solve the problem: please share the minimal code and JSON (as text, no screenshot) that is needed to reproduce the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, I added more code. Probably I will endup adding that update AFTER the transaction is successful (is not a critical update), though is not the best.

Comment: A transaction should run at the highest level that covers all the data that you want to update. If you're updating data outside of that level (like the houses in your case), you should wonder why you're using a transaction to begin with. But this is not a complete repro: what does your JSON structure look like? Where in the JSON tree do you invoke the transaction?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but I want to update objects whose common parent is the root of my db, If I run the transaction from there the mutableData will try to load ALL of the database, isn't this true?

Comment: Yes. So it sounds like transactions are not the solution to your problem in that case. You may have better results running a multi-location update with sufficiently strict server-side security rules.